# Using azure mobile services how do I download a blob from a private container?

Tags: mobile, service, azure, blob

I am using Azure Mobile Services to store images for a web application.
I have managed to successfully upload images to a private container. I've followed the logic in this introductory guide (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190), i.e. when uploading the file to the database an SAS is generated by a node script called when inserting a record into a table.

One of the reasons to use this approach from mobile apps is so that the storage key is not stored within the application source itself.

Conforming with that idea I am now struggling to find an example of how to download the images.

Perhaps I should update the read function for the same table and have that return an SAS which can be used to accessed the image.

Does this sound reasonable or are they better approaches?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are on the right track.  If you are storing the image in a private container and want the mobile device to read it back then yes, you will want to produce a SAS that allows reading and get that back to the device.  The device code can then make a call directly against BLOB storage using that SAS URL to retrieve the image.

This applies only if you want the container private.  If the container is public then just returning the URL (like they have in the article you link to) should be fine.

It also depends on how private you care the image to be.  For example, let's say you have a container created per user.  If the container has a Shared Access Signature Policy on it with a really far off expiration date then technically someone still needs the URL with the SAS to view it, but you can create that SAS and store it like the sample.  The mobile app can then be given the URL when it reads data from your service and get to the BLOB directly without having it create an additional SAS.  In my opinion this option only really works if the images aren't going to be around very long, or you don't really care that if someone sniffs the URL from the network traffic that they can access it.

If you want it fairly secure and do not know how long the images will be around, then you should go with your stated approach of getting a SAS for read when the app reads from the related table data.  The SAS can have a fairly short expiry on it and the mobile device can cache the result.